# Intuitive meaning of logarithmic derivatives?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, logarithms

Suppose you have a derivative $dM/dt$ that gives the rate at which mass increases with time. If the mass M and time t are both expected to evolve over a large dynamic range and take on large values, it is useful for numerical coding purposes to recast $dM/dt$ as the logarithmic derivative $d\log M/d\log t$:

$\frac{dM}{dt} = \frac{M}{t} \frac{d\log M}{d\log t} \iff \frac{d\log M}{d\log t} = \frac{t}{M} \frac{dM}{dt}$

where I used the chain rule $d\log M = (1/M)dM$ and $d\log t = (1/t) dt$.

But what does that new RHS mean in simple intuitive terms? I get that you can further rewrite the RHS as

$\frac{dM/M}{dt/t}$

which is like saying the fractional change of $M$ divided by the fractional change in $t$. So if $\frac{d\log M}{d\log t} = 100$, what would that mean? That $M$ increases by a factor of 100 for every "unit" increase in $t$? Is there a clearer way to phrase what "per unit increase in t" means? The $\log t$ in the denominator is throwing me off.